# Feedback On Release Notes?

Tags: release-notes

It recently came to my attention that the Spring 17 Release Notes contain a typo, [abbreviating Cross-Site Request Forgery to CRSF 11 times](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_vf_crsf_protection_cruc.htm?edition=&impact=). The **[Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/salesforce_release_notes.htm)** page does not seem to have any sort of feedback mechanism to bing this to someone's attention? Can the typo even be fixed?

Comment: I think a case can be logged with support and they can internally raise a request with the documentation team to correct it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest sending a note to https://twitter.com/salesforcedocs. But for this specific issue, I'll submit a bug to have it fixed (I work for Salesforce). Thank you very much!

The comment about entering a support case would work too. Whatever option you choose, it's appreciated.